# SQL Server Backup to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to back up SQL Server Database and than LATER import it into MySQL. Is there any tool for it?

I would rather have portable SQL file(without SQL Server specific SQL)

Comment: Could you do an SQL dump and then bulk import?  I know some syntax might be slightly different, but this is all I can think of.  A tool for this would be ideal though.

Comment: It's completely dependent on whether you're trying to move just the data or if you need to script the table creation etc.  
The biggest concern is how much use of Stored Procedures, functions etc there are within the SQL Server.

Comment: @Joel Mansford I just want to move data and tables. I don't care about indexes,stored procedures and stuff like that. I just want to be able to run the app on other database since I have problem with SQL Server(or it has problem with my machine ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small and medium databases. I've used script from this page.

http://kofler.info/english/mssql2mysql/

http://kofler.info/uploads/mysql/mssql2mysql.txt